# Parallax effect using Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to build this parallax effect in jetpack compose. I am using Horizontal Pager to achieve this.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ParallaxCarousel(
    sliderPaddingValues: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(horizontal = 62.dp, vertical = 24.dp),
) {
    // Get screen dimensions and density
    val screenWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp
    val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp
    val density = LocalDensity.current.density

    // List of image resources
    val images = listOf(
        R.drawable.p1,
        R.drawable.p2,
        R.drawable.p4,
        R.drawable.p2,
        R.drawable.p1,
        R.drawable.p4,
        R.drawable.p1,
    )

    // Create a pager state

    val pageCount = Int.MAX_VALUE
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = pageCount / 2) {
        pageCount
    }

    // Calculate the height for the pager
    val pagerHeight = screenHeight / 1.5f

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {

            // HorizontalPager composable: Swiping through images
            HorizontalPager(
                state = pagerState,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f),
                contentPadding = sliderPaddingValues
            ) { page ->
                // Calculate the parallax offset for the current page
                val parallaxOffset = pagerState.getOffsetFractionForPage(page) * (screenWidth.value / 2)

                val pageOffset =
                    (pagerState.currentPage - page) + pagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction

                val scaleFactor = (0.75f - (1f - 0.75f) * (1f - pageOffset.absoluteValue))
                Log.i("scaleFactor13", pageOffset.toString())

                // Call ParallaxCarouselItem with image resource and parameters
                ParallaxCarouselItem(
                    images[page % images.size],
                    parallaxOffset,
                    pagerHeight,
                    screenWidth,
                    density,
                    scaleFactor
                )
            }
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun ParallaxCarouselItem(
    imageResId: Int,
    parallaxOffset: Float,
    pagerHeight: Dp,
    screenWidth: Dp,
    density: Float,
    scaleFactor: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    imageCornerRadius: Dp = 16.dp,
    imageHeight: Dp = 250.dp,
) {
    // Load the image bitmap
    val imageBitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = imageResId)

    // Card composable for the item
    Box(modifier = modifier
        .graphicsLayer {
            scaleX = scaleFactor
            scaleY = scaleFactor
        }
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(imageCornerRadius))) {
        // Canvas for drawing the image with parallax effect
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clip(shape)
        ) {
            // Translate the canvas for parallax effect
            Log.i("parallaxOffset" , ( parallaxOffset * density + 1000f).toString())
            translate(left = parallaxOffset * density) {
                // Draw the image
                drawImage(
                    image = imageBitmap
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that:

1. I am having an image on the center and a part of the left and right image would be shown on the left and right of the center image with a certain padding. I am able to achieve the parallax effect. But the problem is that when I swipe to the left the image the image is being cropped. I am attaching the screen recording and you could see that the image is being kind of having a cropped effect while the right swipe is normal.

GIF:
https://gifyu.com/image/S6RVT

Comment: you can check it out this link : https://juliensalvi.medium.com/parallax-effect-made-it-simple-with-jetpack-compose-d19bde5688fc